# Set usergroup and persmissions ftp folder back to default

Tags: permissions

I tried to create a new ftp user via the commandline. I did something wrong and now I can access the server via FTP but I can't see any files. It doesn't make any sense wich user I'm using.

```
ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 13 root ftp 4096 2012-03-30 09:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 09:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 13:31 actions
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 11:46 bin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp 1520 2012-03-24 23:32 changelog.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-26 13:30 css
drwxr-xr-x  8 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-24 22:43 external
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp  333 2012-03-26 15:12 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x  3 web6 ftp 4096 2012-02-27 15:07 images
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp 1606 2012-03-26 21:25 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-02-18 13:20 js
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-02-03 00:34 layout
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-29 23:35 library
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-30 09:47 log
-rwxr-xr-x  1 web6 ftp  396 2012-03-24 15:04 menu.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-30 12:01 python
drwxr-xr-x  2 web6 ftp 4096 2012-03-23 10:51 todo
```

I can't see no dirs and files because I changed the groupowner or I changed the rights of the groupowner of the ftp dir.

How can I set the ownership of the files back to default so I can access the files via FTP again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "reset" of permissions, you need to note what they are before the change. It depends what folder you are sharing as to what the defaults should be but at expected less permissions are better than more.

Comment: I dont know what the permissions where before the change. Is their a place where I can find the default permissions for ftp?